# Google Sheet Add-on not updating

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-marketplace

I wrote a Google Apps Script and successfully deployed it as a Google Sheets Add-on.
Yesterday, I found a bug, I updated the script, and I deployed a new version of the add on.

No matter what I do, I still see the old version of the add-on in Google Sheets.

I tried to:
1) Reload the Google Sheet file
2) Uninstall and install the plugin
3) Restart Chrome
4) Re-deploy the add-on

Nothing worked.
How can I force Google Sheets to update to the new version of the plugin?

UPDATE: As pointed out by Alan Wells, this is related to the following bug:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-apps-script-community/WTV2CGFTuHU

Workaround: publishing the plugin from the GCP Marketplace configuration screen worked for me.

Thanks,
Fabio

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache?

Comment: Your issue may be related to a post in the Google Group: [https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-apps-script-community/WTV2CGFTuHU](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-apps-script-community/WTV2CGFTuHU)

Comment: Thanks Alan. I followed the suggested workaround, and I was able to get the plugin updated

Comment: I want to add more information for clarifying the issue: that workaround is the intended way. As you can read on the [publishing docs](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publishing-editor-addons): «*Publishing to the G Suite Marketplace is no longer optional*».

Answer (score 1):

This issue is now fixed. Also the new GSM publishing flow, which no longer requires to publish or update a Chrome Web Store listing, is live.
To update the script of an add-on follow these instructions https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/update-editor-addons#update_published_add-on_code.

Comment: Bro, may I ask when was this fixed? I'm currently investigating an issue with my form-add which took 2 days for the code changes to be reflected in the marketplace.

Comment: It was fixed in mid December. Are you still having the issue?