# Can't update Google Sheet Add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace

I have successfully published an Add-on for Google Sheet and I confirmed that it can be used in the Spreadsheet.
Then I tried to update the Add-on following the instruction in the following doc:
https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/how-tos/update-published-add-on#update_published_add-on_code

But I can't see any updates in the spreadsheet. Anything I might miss?

Answer (score 1):

According to a comment on [How do I update a Google Sheets Add-On](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59395677/how-do-i-update-a-google-sheets-add-on#comment105001430_59396452), it could possibly be that there's a propagation time of 2-3 days for the changes/update to reflect to the servers.

Additionally, there's a comment to an answer on [Google Sheet Add-on not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59216894/google-sheet-add-on-not-updating#comment104964419_59384174) and a community member have shared that it took 2 days for the update changes to reflect on their end. If you've followed precisely the guide from [Update and manage your published add-on](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/how-tos/update-published-add-on#update_published_add-on_code), then propagation time could most likely be the reason.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. It is already 4 days but I don't see the change. I believe I follow all steps at https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/how-tos/update-published-add-on#update_published_add-on_code. Is there anything that I can miss easily?